# remove errored arrays from training arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to train sequential model for image classification.
After exploring resulting X_train, y_train arrays I found that some arrays in X_train are empty -> while trying to run fit_generator I got ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The X_train shape is (2122,), the y_train shape is (2122, 28).

How can I safely delete empty objects from X_train and y_train arrays knowing index?

X_train was generated by following function:

```
def normalize_image(image):
    try:
        return np.array(cv2.resize(image, (img_size, img_size))).astype("float32") / 255.0        
    except Exception as e:
        pass

 X = np.array([normalize_image(img_data.get_pixels()) for img_data in imgs_data])
```

and looks like this:

```
array([array([[[0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8784314 ],
    [0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8745098 ],
    [0.8039216 , 0.8509804 , 0.8666667 ],
    ...,
    [0.77254903, 0.78431374, 0.8039216 ],
    [0.7764706 , 0.7882353 , 0.80784315],
    [0.78039217, 0.7921569 , 0.8117647 ]],

   [[0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8784314 ],
    [0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8745098 ],
    [0.8039216 , 0.8509804 , 0.8666667 ],
    ...,
    [0.77254903, 0.78431374, 0.8039216 ],
    [0.76862746, 0.78039217, 0.8       ],
    [0.77254903, 0.78431374, 0.8039216 ]],

   [[0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8784314 ],
    [0.80784315, 0.84313726, 0.8745098 ],
    [0.8039216 , 0.8509804 , 0.8666667 ],
    ...,
    [0.77254903, 0.78431374, 0.8039216 ],
    [0.7764706 , 0.7882353 , 0.80784315],
    [0.77254903, 0.7882353 , 0.8039216 ]],

   ...,

   [[0.7921569 , 0.80784315, 0.8509804 ],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    ...,
    [0.23529412, 0.39607844, 0.5254902 ],
    [0.24313726, 0.39215687, 0.5294118 ],
    [0.23921569, 0.3882353 , 0.5254902 ]],

   [[0.7921569 , 0.80784315, 0.8509804 ],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    ...,
    [0.23529412, 0.39607844, 0.5254902 ],
    [0.24313726, 0.39215687, 0.5294118 ],
    [0.23137255, 0.38039216, 0.5176471 ]],

   [[0.7921569 , 0.80784315, 0.8509804 ],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    [0.79607844, 0.8117647 , 0.85490197],
    ...,
    [0.22352941, 0.38431373, 0.5137255 ],
    [0.24313726, 0.39215687, 0.5294118 ],
    [0.24313726, 0.39215687, 0.5294118 ]]], dtype=float32),
    ...
    [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
X = np.array([v for v in [normalize_image(img_data.get_pixels()) for img_data in imgs_data] if np.sum(v[0]) > 0])
```

This should exclude every image with only zeros.

Edit:

You still need to do the same for y I guess, so you can do the following to do it for both at the same time:

```
pairs = [pair for pair in [(normalize_image(x.get_pixels()), y) for x, y in zip(imgs_data, Y)] if np.sum(pair[0]) > 0]
```

Afterwards you can create X and Y by doing:

```
X = np.array([x[0] for x in pairs])
Y = np.array([x[1] for x in pairs])
```